# How do exclusive locks work with Triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Firstly, I will try to create a picture of what I am trying to do:-

1. Taken up hosting in a shared server (godaddy).
2. Publishing a few APIs which will be accessed by a number of clients to get/push data from/to the server
3. The server's database has only 1 table which contains the data. Data isn't that huge - about 10 columns and would probably not exceed 10,000 rows in the foreseeable future. Basically, there are going to be 10-15 record inserts in a day.
4. Information from the clients will result in inserts and update on existing rows. Therefore, clients will call APIs to read as well as update things in the database

Is having 1 table a very bad idea, assuming there can be over 1000 client requests accessing the server to read and update information every day.

If it is a bad idea and I were to create mirror tables while trying to distribute client requests, then they would need triggers to ensure that the information in each table remains the same. What I am not able to understand is what happens if there is a lock on table, which on update triggers an insert or update on another table, whose lock is preoccupied with another client.

It will be bad to see the connections to time out solely due to the wait time for locks to be released (in case the number of client requests to the database are just on the higher side at some point in time).

Comment: 10,000 rows with 10-15 inserts a day is tiny. Why do you even need a mirror on this?

Comment: There will be 10-15 inserts a day, but as I've mentioned, there will be about (or a little over) 1000 client requests which will be either select or update commands. We can take about 500 updates, 500 read requests and just about 10-15 inserts a day